# simulating parallel endpoint api usage via jmeter

Tags: rest, mobile, jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

I have rest endpoint under test.
In real world scenario, this API will be called in parallel by 100-200 users/minute.

I would like to simulate such scenario via jmeter as load testing.
I've created simple thread group with thread count 100, but I am not quit sure whether it's doing what I am looking for.

Does the thread count represents the actual parallel consumers?
How can I simulate such parallel access to endpoint API?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One thread means one Vuser or Number of Threads means Number of users to simulate.

From jmeter [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html):-

> Each thread will execute the test plan in its entirety and completely
>   independently of other test threads. Multiple threads are used to
>   simulate concurrent connections to your server application.

So, multiple thread will run the plan in parallel with some delay specify in ramp up field of [thread group.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Hope this helps.